# Performance issue in select query jdbc conncetion to Mysql in Azure databricks

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am doing an JDBC connection to Mysql database in Azure databricks env. Then trying retrieve the count(id) with date range of 24 hrs and IN filter with specific country, but its taking hell lot of time. How can I improve the performance?

Query:

```
pushdown_query = """(select count(id) from Mysql_database where time > "{}" and time < "{}" and country IN ('FRA','AUT','DEU','CZE')) alias""".format(From_date,To_date)

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is Mysql_database really large? If so you may need to add some indexes to the table if they are not there already

Comment: Thank you for your response.Yes its large.I will try adding indexes.